# Write log in Excel after mail send or receive in outlook using Macro

Tags: excel, vba, logging, outlook

I need your help to create a macro in Outlook 2010 which will store the From,To,Date,Subject,Flag in an excel after sending any mail form an account or receiving any mail in the inbox of that account.

In that process i tried to create the log first in excel after sending mail with some default value by using below code. But it is giving error "Compile Error, Sub or Function not defined" at line:

```
Windows("Access_Log.xlsx").Activate
```

The code goes as below:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Workbooks.Open FileName:="\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx"
Windows("Access_Log.xlsx").Activate


'Sheets("log").Activate
If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
n = 1
Else
n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If
Cells(n, "A").Value = Environ("username")
Cells(n, "b").Value = Date
Cells(n, "c").Value = Time
Cells(n, "d").Value = "Outlook"
Cells(n, "E").Value = "sent mail"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

It is written in ThisOutlookSession --> Application --> SendItem.

Any help to this code and the original requirement will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Maitreya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an Excel file from Outlook-VBA you first need create an Excel application:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

if you don't want the Excel to show use

```
xlApp.Visible = False
```

to hide it. And then you can open an Excel file in that application:

```
Dim xlWb As Object
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="\\Bmcstr01\grp\SRV\Allsrv\NEW Complaints Logger\GI Complaints\Spreadsheets\Archieve\Access_Log.xlsx")
```

and then you can access a worksheet in that file:

```
Dim xlWs As Object
Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'put your sheet name here
```

and then comes your code accessing this worksheet like

```
Const xlUp = -4162 'see explanation below

Dim n As Long
With xlWs
    If .Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        n = 1
    Else
        n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    .Cells(n, "A").Value = Environ("username")
    .Cells(n, "B").Value = Date
    .Cells(n, "C").Value = Time
    .Cells(n, "D").Value = "Outlook"
    .Cells(n, "E").Value = "sent mail"
End With

xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True 'close and save workbook
```

Edit//

Note that `xlUp` does not exist in Outlook. Therefore you need to use `-4162` or define a constant for it `Const xlUp = -4162` before you can use it.

Comment: Hi, What is the meaning of putting -4162? What is the value stand for?

Comment: Hi, Now the macro is not giving any error, but seems that it is not inserting any record in the log file.

Comment: I have checked... that the macro is even not running at all. After sending any mail Outlook is not at all reading the codes.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for help. it was for macro security settings.